# Number of solutions for $a+b+c+ab+bc+ac+abc=29$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Let the number N be the smallest three digit number with digits $a,b,c$. $a+b+c+ab+bc+ca +abc=29$. Evaluate $\frac{N+1}{5}$.

By adding $1$ on both sides we get $(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)=30$. How should I proceed further and  is there any way without hit and trial?

Answer (score 4):

We want to find the smallest $N$ possible, so minimise each digit one at a time.

$a \ne 0$ so the smallest $a$ is $1$. This gives $(b+1)(c+1) = 15$ and you can continue from here.